# What is the correct term for a module but with the scalars being elements of a monoid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

From my understanding, a module is similar to a vector space over a field, except the scalars come from a ring. What about the cases when the scalars come from a monoid? Is there a specific term used when the scalars are from a monoid instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people call them [monoid actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup_action), by analogy with [group actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). There's also the term "monoid act," but I don't know who uses it.

Answer (score 1):

We call them modules over the monoid. In general, for a monoid object $M$ in a monoidal category $\mathbf{C}$, we call objects of $\mathbf{C}$ on which $M$ acts $M$-modules. These form a category. See [this](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mod) for more information.

Comment: "Subcategory" seems like a really misleading thing to say here. They're certainly not a full subcategory. (Would you call the category of groups a subcategory of the category of sets?) At best, there's just a forgetful functor from $M$-modules to objects of $C$.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I've edited my answer.